# Coloring a region programmatically based by user selection with Highmaps

Tags: highcharts, theming

I have an application where user can select a region by clicking. Then the map rewrites itself and zoomsTo() to the selected area. So far everything else works, but I haven't get any idea how to color the selected area programmatically. The area (or different statistics) may also be selected from a drop-down list, so I have to redraw the map in any case.

`var mapChart=$('#mapcontainer').highcharts();
mapChart.get(jQuery( "#selected-region" ).val()).zoomTo();
mapChart.mapZoom(5);`

I have tried things along the line:

```
mapChart.get(jQuery( "#selected-region" ).val()).color="rgb(255,0,0)";
```

but so far no breakthrough :/

Any ideas?

hank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jquery to select point is not the best solution. Highcharts provides point events like `click` where you have an access to clicked point instance, or you can select a point using the [chart.get()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#get) method by point id.

To change the selected area color you have to define color property when a point (area) is selected:

```
series: [{
  states: {
    select: {
      color: '#a4edba'
    }
  }
}]
```

Now you have to invoke [select()](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#select) method on the clicked or selected point, as well as you invoked `zoomTo()` method:

```
  series: [{
      point: {
        events: {
          click: function() {
            var point = this;

            point.zoomTo();
            point.select();
          }
        }
      },
      states: {
        select: {
          color: '#a4edba'
        }
      }
    }]
  });
```

Demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/wchmiel/yzco1023/

Comment: Thank you, I try to check this. I actually made a work-around by adding more logic to the  the back-end. But anyhow, there will be situations, where back-end isn't a good solution

Comment: You're welcome. If you like this answer, please mark it as the correct answer or upvote. Thanks.